# How can I return JSON struct with an HTTP status in Rocket 0.5.0-rc.2?

Tags: json, rust, rust-rocket

I'm searching a clean and good way to return json responses with the right HTTP status using Rocket 0.5.0-rc.2. I want something versatile that I can use to return error messages (in case of error) but also JSON results (in case of 200) from structs.

I'm using Rocket 0.5.0-rc.2 with the latest stable Rust version.

I have an Rocket API like this:

```
#[delete("/customers/<id>")]
pub async fn delete_customer(
    db: &State<Database>,
    id: String,
) -> ApiResponse<Customer> {
```

When I call this API with a valid `id` I want a **status 200** with a JSON payload like this:

```
{
   "name": "removed-customer" // this is only an example to show some data
}
```

When I call this API with an un-existing `id` I want a **status 404** with a JSON payload like this:

```
{
   "message": "unexisting id"
}
```

I can accept a fixed struct as json error, for instance a generic one like:

```
{
  "message": "bad params error message",
}
```

with "message" and the status is the "HTTP status".

**But for 200 response I need to return variable structs as JSON response**, for instance to return an array of Customers if I create a get_customer API.

I saw an interesting solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70563341/3590376) using a struct `ApiResponse`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct ApiResponse<T> {
    json: Json<T>,
    status: Status,
}

impl<'r, T: serde::Serialize> Responder<'r> for ApiResponse<T> {
    fn respond_to(self, req: &Request) -> response::Result<'r> {
        Response::build_from(self.json.respond_to(&req).unwrap())
            .status(self.status)
            .header(ContentType::JSON)
            .ok()
    }
}
```

but this is not working in 0.5.0-rc.2 because Respondertakes 2 lifetime arguments, so I updated this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ApiResponse<T> {
    pub json: Json<T>,
    pub status: Status,
}

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl<'r, T> Responder<'r, 'r> for ApiResponse<T> {
    fn respond_to(self, req: &'r Request<'_>) -> Result<'static> {
        Response::build_from(self.json.respond_to(&req).unwrap())
            .status(self.status)
            .header(ContentType::JSON)
            .ok()
    }
}
```

But again, it isn't working, because:

```
the method `respond_to` exists for struct `rocket::serde::json::Json<T>`,
but its trait bounds were not satisfied E0599 method cannot be called on
`rocket::serde::json::Json<T>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
Note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`T: models::customer::_::_serde::Serialize` 
which is required by `rocket::serde::json::Json<T>: rocket::response::Responder`
```

Probably, this is the wrong way to do this, because I have to use T = Customer in api method definition, so I cannot return a struct for Errors and Customer and the same time.
I'm open to new and better approaches.
Which is the recommended way to do this?

Is it better to use `Value` like this? :

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ApiResponse {
    pub json: Value,
    pub status: Status,
}
```

and then use it in this way?:

- error case

```
return ApiResponse {
 json: json!({"message": "error message"}),
 status: Status::BadRequest,
};
```

or also creating a custom Error struct with "message" field?

- success case

```
return ApiResponse {
 json: serde_json::to_value(customer).unwrap(),
 status: Status::BadRequest,
};
```